# Lubuntu and backup software?

Tags: lubuntu, deja-dup

I use unity and I appreciate the backup facilities incorporate since 12.04 (deja dup).

Is it possible to use it with Lubuntu ? One of the advantages of the integration of deja dup in unity is the possiblity to recover a file by a right clic in a directory where that file was located. Is it possible to do that in lubuntu ?

Comment: one of the best and simple utilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same file manager integration, you must install and use nautilus, the GNOME file manager.

Alternatively, you could do something like the following in a terminal:
  deja-dup --restore /path/to/file

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason not to continue using deja dup as your backup manager.

It is fully supported through 13.04 as I use it currently in Lubuntu, version 25.3-Ounbunu1.

You can install this using the Software Center, Synaptic or CLI in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install deja-dup
```

[image]

Comment: Nice ! How did you obtain this window ?

Comment: @Ger used "shutter"->window capture

Comment: :) No I would like to say, where should I go in order to do that ?

Comment: WHAT EXACTLY ARE YOU ASKING? where to get the application - how to use the application - where I got deja dup - How toi use deja dup - I just can't follow your thinking here. Be specific.

Comment: I use Lubuntu 12.10. If I go to system tools -> backup I can chose to restore a backup but I must restore all files. I am looking for a way to be able to restore only one file or at least one directory.

Comment: @Ger the image you see above I cannot duplicate, for whatever reason. It was generated on the First Run of deja-dup. SORRY.

Answer (score 0):

@Ger Answering my interpretation of your question (which is identical with the question I had 5 five minutes ago): Deja Dup becomes accessible (launch-able) through the menu items **Accessories -> Backups** and **Preferences -> Backups**.  That's my experience in Lubuntu 16.04.2, anyway.  I noticed neither until after logging out and logging back in.  Since I made some effort to find an appropriate menu item, I'm happy to conclude they were not there until after my new log in.  (Rather than log out, there's very probably something less disruptive you can do, such as restarting the window manager, to attain the same goal.)

The initial state of the Deja Dup window was not a good match with Ringtail's screen shot.