# Are there any backup utilities for Lubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, backup

My hard disk recently started doing some weird things like shutting down at random times. I checked GNOME Disks and found out that it is likely to fail soon. So, I started searching for backup utilities. However, the only thing that Software Center showed me was GNOME Disks.

So, I tried to create an image of my partition, but then I realized that my backup disk does not have that much space (my Lubuntu installation is on a 80 GB partition, 27 GB used, tried creating an image on a 75 GB disk).

I tried to find Timeshift (the  backup utility that is used in Linux Mint), but to no avail. Neither in Software Center, nor with `apt` (could not find package `timeshift`).

So are there any backup utilities available except GNOME Disks? Because I don't want to spend 1h 30min for the whole `/home` folder to copy.

Comment: Ubuntu comes with `backup` preinstalled. Doesn't Lubuntu?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/209512/lubuntu-and-backup-software

Comment: You could use Deja Dup or tar with a hard drive or cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Timeshift like this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timeshift
```

Visit this link to learn how to use it or do a search yourself - your call

https://itsfoss.com/backup-restore-linux-timeshift/

Comment: It worked! I have a complete snapshot of my system now!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure Timeshift is an excellent solution from the previous answer, however for the sake of completeness, I thought of suggesting Deja Dup. This is the most common Ubuntu program for this task. Deja Dup has adopted the simpler name Backups in recent releases like 22.04 (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1490425/222247).

You can install it from the Software application:
[image: DejaDupInstallOnSoftware]

You can also install it from the Synaptic Package Manager if you have it installed:
[image]